# Improper MySQL Syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason my code is giving me an error, and I can't figure out why. Here's the error:

```
INSERT INTO organization (org_name, add_1, add_2, city, state, zip, url, email, phone, contact, hours, file_loc, notes, description, group) VALUES('testmi', '333', '', '', 'MI', '', 'www.blah.com', '', '888-999-2222', '', '', '', '', '', 'Michigan')QUERROR 3You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group) VALUES('testmi', '333', '', '', 'MI', '', 'www.blah.com', ''' at line 1
```

And here's the code:

```
$sqlInsertOrg = "INSERT INTO organization (org_name, add_1, add_2, city, state, zip, url, email, phone, contact, hours, file_loc, notes, description, group)
             VALUES('".$org_name."', '".$add_1."', '".$add_2."', '".$city."', '".$state."', '".$zip."', '".$url."', '".$email."', '".$phone."', '".$contact."', '".$hours."', '".$file_loc."', '".$notes."', '".$description."', '".$group."')";
```

Comment: Try and put your variables without the ".$var." and just do "$var", keep everything all in one line, just helps readability.

Answer (score 4):

`GROUP` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. Escape it with backticks (`) and you'll be fine.

```
INSERT INTO organization (org_name, ... `group`) ...
```